# Why numbers of the form $2^{2t} ± 3$ are primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Why $p=2^{2t}±3$  are primes?

Take a Mersenne number(prime or no-prime) $2^t-1$, multiply it by its conjugate $2^t+1$ and subtract $ 2$, the resulted number seems to be prime(probably most of them):

I checked $p=2^{2t} ±3$ following program in Python up to $t=20$:

for s in range (2, 20):

```
 t=2*s

 n=2**t-3

 a=n**0.5

 b=int(a)

 isprime =True

 for x in range(2, b+1):

     if n%x == 0:

         print n, '=', x, '*', n/x

         isprime = False

         break

 if(isprime):

        print n, 'is prime'
```

gievs:

13 is prime

61 is prime

253 = 11 * 23

1021 is prime

4093 is prime

16381 is prime

65533 = 13 * 5041

262141 = 11 * 23831

1048573 is prime

4194301 is prime

16777213 is prime

67108861 = 37 * 1813753

268435453 = 11 * 24403223

1073741821 = 23 * 46684427

4294967293 = 9241 * 464773

17179869181 = 5113 * 3360037

68719476733 = 242819 * 283007

274877906941 = 11 * 24988900631

for s in range (2, 20):

```
 t=2*s

 n=2**t+3

 a=n**0.5

 b=int(a)

 isprime =True

 for x in range(2, b+1):

     if n%x == 0:

         print n, '=', x, '*', n/x

         isprime = False

         break

 if(isprime):

        print n, 'is prime'
```

gives:

19 is prime

67 is prime

259 = 7 * 37

1027 = 13 * 79

4099 is prime

16387 = 7 * 2341

65539 is prime

262147 is prime

1048579 = 7 * 149797

4194307 = 13 * 322639

16777219 = 1549 * 10831

67108867 = 7 * 9586981

268435459 is prime

1073741827 is prime

4294967299 = 7 * 613566757

17179869187 = 13 * 1321528399

68719476739 = 61 * 1126548799

274877906947 = 7 * 39268272421

Point 1- We can see many twin primes with difference 6 such as $13$and $19$ which are for $t=2$, or $4093$ and $4099$ which are for $t=6$. This finding supports the idea that there can be infinite twin primes with a certain difference.

point 2-For $2^{2t}+3$ we can see that:

$2^6 ≡ 1 \ mod (7)$

⇒ $2^2\times 2^6 ≡ 2^2 \ mod(7)$

⇒ $2^8 +3≡ 0 \mod (7) $

Hence the set of numbers $t= \{4, 7, 10, 13, . . . \} $ gives numbers which are  divisible by $7$.

Question: We know that the greatest prime is a Mersenne prime, how can we be sure that this operations on it will not give a greater prime? If the power of $2$ in greatest prime is a member of the set $t$, we can be sure that $2^{2t}+3$ is divisible by $7$; if not we must check it out.

Comment: Don't let prime numbers decieve you ;)

Comment: Both your `if` and `else` have a `break` in them, so you're only testing `x=3` before you break out of the `x` loop.

Comment: @nickgard, thanks for your comment, b I could not repair my program!

Comment: $2^{31}-1$ is a Mersenne *prime*, but $2^{62}-3$ is divisible by $37$

Comment: Can you please change the header in something like ,,Why is ... sometimes prime?‘‘

Answer (score 5):

PARI/GP says that primes among these numbers are not as ubiquitous as you believe:

```
? for(t=2,25,p=2^(2*t)-3;if(!isprime(p),print([t,p,factor(p)])))
[4, 253, [11, 1; 23, 1]]
[8, 65533, [13, 1; 71, 2]]
[9, 262141, [11, 1; 23831, 1]]
[13, 67108861, [37, 1; 349, 1; 5197, 1]]
[14, 268435453, [11, 1; 13, 1; 1877171, 1]]
[15, 1073741821, [23, 1; 46684427, 1]]
[16, 4294967293, [9241, 1; 464773, 1]]
[17, 17179869181, [5113, 1; 3360037, 1]]
[18, 68719476733, [242819, 1; 283007, 1]]
[19, 274877906941, [11, 1; 12589, 1; 1984979, 1]]
[20, 1099511627773, [13, 1; 84577817521, 1]]
[21, 4398046511101, [47, 1; 193, 1; 4463, 1; 108637, 1]]
[22, 17592186044413, [5927, 1; 2968143419, 1]]
[23, 70368744177661, [227, 1; 19273, 1; 16084391, 1]]
[24, 281474976710653, [11, 1; 167, 1; 239, 1; 641110271, 1]]
[25, 1125899906842621, [59, 1; 176329, 1; 108224111, 1]]
```

It seems (tested up to $t=800$) that $t=2,3,5,6,7,10,11,12$ are perhaps the *only* cases that produce a prime.

**UPDATE:** $2^{2\cdot 868}-3$ is also prime. But that is the only other case up to $t=1976$. (Beyond that I would have had to increase my stack size, but didn't want to)